# Como ver se uma string possui números

Tags: c++, string

Quero fazer um programa que leia uma string e retorne "+" na frente de todos os números.
Exemplo

entrada:

a 1 2 b 3

saída:

a +1 +2 b +3

eu fiz isso:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


bool isdigit(char c)
{
 
    if(c>='0' && c<='9')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


int main ()
{
    string str;
    cin >> str;


    for (int i=0; i < str.length(); ++i) {

         if (isdigit(str[i])==true){
                cout << " +" << str[i];
         }
         else
            cout << str[i];
    }

return 0;
}
```

Porém não está funcionando. Não entendi pq, pra mim essa lógica daria certo... Alguém pode me explicar porque isso não funciona?

Comment: `str[i]` indica o caractere da posição i e não uma string. Tente `if (isdigit(str)==true){` e não posição a posição, ou modifique o parâmetro de sua função.

Comment: tentei if (isdigit(str)==true) mas não deu também.... ai se eu fosse mudar o parâmetro eu colocaria o que? char c?

Comment: no caso, quando eu coloco uma string ele está retornando apenas o 1 elemento

Comment: O problema é que você está tentando fazer a leitura da string com cin. O primeiro espaço encerra a entrada. Utilize: `getline(cin, str);` no lugar de `cin >> str;`.

Comment: Aaaah!! Agora deu!! Muito obrigada!

Comment: Existe algum jeito de analisar numeros maiores? Por exemplo, se eu colocar 123, ele está retornando +1 +2 +3 ao invés de +123.

Answer (score 0):

Ana,

Uma letra só já é uma `string`. Use algo para ler a linha toda, como `getline()`.

Ainda sobre seu programa, note que

- não precisa reescrever `isdigit()` porque ela está disponível em C++. Pode ter que incluir `<ctype.h>`
- como `isdigit()` retorna `bool` não precisa comparar com `true`
- chaves em comandos únicos são opcionais

Então bastaria

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str = "a 1 2 b 3";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length();i+=1) 
      if (isdigit(str[i]))
        cout << " +" << str[i];
      else
        cout << str[i];
    return 0;
}
```

**Ou talvez algo como**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str = "a 1 2 b 3";
    for (auto& letra : str) 
      if (isdigit(letra))
        cout << " +" << letra;
      else
        cout << letra;
    return 0;
}
```

que talvez seja mais fácil de ler e não precisa do índice. C++ desde 2011 sabe que iterar por uma `significa` tratar as letras uma a uma.